# Changing the administrator's password

Tags: password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative (root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my computer along with Windows X P OS.I forgot the password given at the beginning.And I gave my full name as user name with a gap in between my two names.Now I cannot log in as an administrator. What should I do ? Please help me.